# Pronounciation of first aya of Surah Humaza

Tags: quran, surah

As salamu alaykum.

The first aya of surah 104 ends with a "taa" (if I'm not mistaken) however upon listening to recitations, reciters end the aya with a "ha" sound, saying ".....lumazah."

I was wondering under which circumstances the letter "taa" is pronounced as a "ha"?

I believe in this circumstance it is written like a ha BUT with two dots on top of it, making it look like a taa.

Furthermore, there is a very small (letter) "nun" at the end of the aya. Should this also be pronounced? If not, could you please explain why it is there?

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pronounced as lumazah when making a pause at the end of the first ayah. Check the recitation with pause: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEHUaGHyNFU

It is pronounced as lumazatin ilathi when you connect the two ayat. The نِ denotes the n sound. Check the joint recitation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIAc6_n6Tb0

Generally ة is pronounced as ha if pausing on the letter and as ta without a pause.

Comment: Thank you! So just to clarify is it more correct to connect the two ayat, especially due to the fact that there is a lam alif indicating that we should not discontinue reading? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @H.Quader Both ways are correct. When there is لا on an ayah ending sign ۝ there is difference of opinion, so you can pause or continue.